# Android KitKat: Snackbar is not in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I add a Snackbar to my app. The problem is that in API 19 it's not at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

In API 21 it's ok. Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data />
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/home_search_input_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

And my `OnCreate`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // binding
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home);


    // snackbar test
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

    snackbar.show();
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

UPDATE: It seems that margin from the bottom is really random, I rerun emulator and see this.

[image]

and this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be avoided by moving the code which shows snackbar to onGlobalLayout() like following.

```
binding.root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                // snackbar test
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.show();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    binding.root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    binding.root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How does this solution work when the snackbar is triggered by an external event like a button click?

Answer (score 4):

If you use 26 or 27 support, it is probably this known bug: [Google Issue Tracker: Snackbar wrong placement on the Android 4x versions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64285517)

Comment: It happens on Android 4.1 and 4.2 as well.

Answer (score 4):

To workaround it, use a small time delay before showing the Snackbar. This is needed if you want to show the Snackbar immediately when the screen displays, in `onCreateView()` or `onCreate()`.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // For com.android.support:design:v26 or v27, use a small
        // time delay, to prevent bottom gap bug on Android 4.4
        if (isAdded()) { snackbar.show(); }
    }
}, 500);
```

Because you have a time delay, remember to protect against null Activity by checking for `isAdded()` or check `getActivity() != null`.

Comment: for me 200 ms was enough

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64285517) which is still not fixed.

Workaround - small delay on pre-lollipop devices.
Delay not noticeable on UI.

Put these methods in your base fragment and base activity and use everywhere:

```
protected ViewGroup getRootView() {
    return (ViewGroup) getView().getParent();
}

protected void showSnackbar(@StringRes int resId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Snackbar.make(getRootView(), resId, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), 200);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(getRootView(), resId, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void showSnackbar(String message) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> Snackbar.make(getRootView(), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), 200);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(getRootView(), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```